# removing zsh broke my terminal

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, bashrc, default, zsh

I ran this code `sudo apt-get --purge remove zsh` to delete zsh and now my terminal has this output:

and when accessing through powershell:

<3>WSL (556) ERROR: CreateProccessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh failed 2

I using UBUNTU 20

Comment: Can you run `wsl -e bash` from PowerShell? If so, you should then be able to use `chsh -s /bin/bash` to reset your user's shell to the default bash. See for example [Deleted Shell on WSL and Cannot Access WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257860/deleted-shell-on-wsl-and-cannot-access-wsl)